# Getting valgrind errors when trying to free int pointer array. Not sure why

Tags: c, pointers, valgrind, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is my code/valgrind errors. Can someone help me figure out where I am going wrong.

```
struct Stores{
    int storeNumber;
    int *itemCost;
} Stores;

Stores store;
store = calloc(1,numStores*sizeof(store));

store.itemCost = (int*) calloc(1, numItems*sizeof(int)); //(numItems = 2)

store.itemCost[0] = 10;
store.itemCost[1] = 10;

free(store.itemCost);  <---- Error here
free(store);
```

The valgrind error I am getting:

```
--Invalid read of size 8
```

Comment: __Please do not edit to change the question once you've got the answer.__ You can always ___add___ additional information keeping the original question unchanged.

Comment: More idiomatic to code `store.itemCost = calloc(sizeof *store.itemCost, numItems);`

Comment: when assigning the returned value from `calloc()` the receiver of the assignment must be a pointer, not an instance of a struct. so this line has two problems: `Stores store;`
  1)  the `Stores` is an 'incomplete type` so will not compile.  2) the receiver of a pointer needs to be a pointer.  Suggest: `struct Stores *store;`

Comment: Since `stores` is now a pointer, all the references should be: `store->itemCost`.

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions: (calloc, malloc, realloc) 1) do not cast the returned value.  The returned value has type `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making understanding, debug, maintenance much more difficlut.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: after fixing the other problems in the code, then this line: `store = calloc(1,numStores*sizeof(store));` needs to be corrected (because now `store` is just a pointer) to: `store = calloc(1,numStores*sizeof( struct Stores));`   BTW: an appropriate amount of horizontal spacing makes the code much easier to read.  I.E. `store = calloc( 1, numStores * sizeof( struct Stores ) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, without a `typedef` in place,

```
Stores store;
```

is wrong. `Stores` is not a *type*, anyway.

Considering

```
typedef struct Stores{
    int storeNumber;
    int *itemCost;
} Stores;
```

and then

```
Stores store;
```

you don't need to (*rather, can not*) `calloc()`, at all.

In case you want to play with allocate dynamic memory, you need to change

```
Stores *store;  // a pointer
```

and the related member access operators from `.` to `->`, as applicable.

***Moral of the story: Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them.***

That said, for the first `calloc()`, you did not cast the returned value, don't do it next time, either.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, somehow missed the *.

Comment: @J.Doe Nopes, you did not. `store.itemCost` would not have compiled then.

Comment: That is exactly what I have:/ and my program is running fine. Its just the valgrind error.

Comment: what compiler do you use?

Comment: @bruceg I am using gcc.

Comment: @J.Doe What version and what arguments do you use?

Comment: This is my compile flags: -Wall -std=c11 -g. 
 
Also if i change the . to -> i get the error: "Invalid type argument of '->'(have struct Stores)

Comment: @J.Doe, so you __did not__ `somehow missed the *`, actually?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yea, this is very puzzling to me too. If I make it Stores **store, the -> works.